# Trigonometric Function Modeling

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

**Question**: In a normal respiratory cycle the volume of air that moves into and out of the lungs is about $500$ mL. The reserve and residue volumes of air that remain in the lungs occupy about $2000$ mL and a single respiratory cycle for an average human takes about $4$ seconds. Find a model for the total volume of air $V(t)$ in the lungs as a function of time.

**Answer**: $$500\sin\bigg(\frac{\pi}2t\bigg) + 2000$$

Am I correct? If not, then could you explain where I went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can spot one problem. It seems to me that the answer *should* be
$$500\sin\bigg(\frac{\pi t}{2}\bigg)+2500$$
Because the question makes it sound like there should be at least $2000$mL of air in the lungs *at all times*, and with your model, the amount of air may dip down to $1500$ when the sinusoidal part of your function hits a minimum of $-500$. But other than that, it looks good!

**EDIT:** As noted by @lulu, it's possible that the writer of this question may have intended the answer to be
$$250\sin\bigg(\frac{\pi t}{2}\bigg)+2250$$
because this allows for a $500$mL *difference* from $2000$mL in the lungs, rather than a $500$mL range above and one below $2000$mL.

Comment: But with this choice then you have $V(t)$ ranging from $2000$ to $3000$ so it seems that $1000$ is flowing in and out.  Maybe better to change the amplitude to $250$ and $V(0)$ to $2250$?

Comment: @lulu True... the question seems not to be specific enough to tell for sure whether your interpretation or mine was what the question-writer had in mind. I'm going to leave my solution in the answer, but I will add yours as a second interpretation.

Comment: Sure.  To my reading, the $500$ should be a "peak to trough" differential.  I can certainly see where other readings might be possible.

Comment: @Nilknarf Thank you for your response. I had the answer you gave in mind, however I ended up changing it due to the simple fact that once the breathing period is complete, there should still be reserve or residue of 2000 mL remaining. But with 2500 as 'C' value, means that the function starts from 2500 mL and not from the residue of 2000 mL which is what the person should have in the lungs at all times. I have showed this question to three people and everyone has a different interpretation and answer.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, normal tidal volume (max to min) in a normal healthy human being is $500$ ml, so this would support the answer $250\sin(\pi t/2)+2250$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_volume

Comment: @Iamlearningmath You can adjust the phase of the sinusoid. If you want the minimum value to coincide with the start of the cycle (i.e., $t=0$), then shift it by $\pi/2$, (which you can do by switching $\sin$ to $-\cos$).

Answer (score 0):

With a period $4$ second we observe:
\begin{cases}
t=0 ; V(t)=2000,\\
t=1 ; ?,\\
t=2 ; V(t)=2500,\\
t=3 ; ?.
\end{cases}
for a regular respiratory cycle we guess the amount of volume in lung
\begin{cases}
t=0 ; V(0)=2000,\\
t=1 ; V(1)=2250,\\
t=2 ; V(2)=2500,\\
t=3 ; V(3)=2250.
\end{cases}
these points make a periodic model which can be as a Fourier series. So with discrete (time) Fourier series for $\{2000,2250,2500,2250\}$ we have from main topics that for $k$ observed points $\{z_1,z_2,z_3,\cdots,z_k\}$ in a model the series is
$$f(t)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{q}\Big(a_n\cos\frac{2n\pi}{k}t+b_n\sin\frac{2n\pi}{k}t\Big)$$
where $a_0$, $a_n$ and $b_n$ are:
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_0 &=& \frac{2}{k}\sum_{t=1}^kz_t                    \\
a_n &=& \frac{2}{k}\sum_{t=1}^kz_t\cos\frac{2n\pi}{k}t ~~~~~,~~~~~n=1,2,\cdots,q \\
b_n &=& \frac{2}{k}\sum_{t=1}^kz_t\sin\frac{2n\pi}{k}t ~~~~~,~~~~~n=1,2,\cdots,q
\end{eqnarray*}
and here $k=4$ and $q=\dfrac{k}{2}=2$ and $n=2$ so we find $a_1=a_2=b_1=0$ and $b_2=-250$. These coefficients make the series
$$\color{blue}{f(t)=2250-250\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}t\right)}$$